# Позиционирование элементов

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, position

Почему в [этом примере](http://jsfiddle.net/5Xx8E/) несмотря на то, что свойство margin-top указано у одного элемента смещаются по вертикали все? Как исправить, не меняя свойств отображения элемента (`position`, `display`)?

```css
.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.wrap a {
  position: static;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px 0;
  background: #bbb;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <a href=""></a>
  <a href="" style="margin-top: 10px;"></a>
  <a href=""></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<s>` Свойство указано не у одного, а у всех дочерних элементов с тэгом `а`. Задайте класс или идентификатор каждому элементу, который хотите сместить.

**UPD**

У ссылок стоит дефолтное

```
vertical-align: baseline;
```

Задайте выравнивание по верху и будет счастье.

Comment: в html инлайн вставка стиля у второй ссылки: style="margin-top: 10px;". Инлайн вставки в css приоритетней, насколько мне известно.